# How does potential of a plate of a charging capacitor remain constant, even though charge on the plate is changing?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, capacitance

[image]

[image]

Suppose a capacitor is being charged in an RC circuit as given in the pictures attached above, initially the charge on both plates of capacitor is 0, as the capacitor gets charged, a potential difference is created between the plates of the capacitor, but as per the pictures, the potential of only the left plate is changing, and the potential of the right plate remains constant at 0V , a common explanation of this is that a conductor connected to the terminal of a battery, has the same potential as that terminal, and as the potential of the terminals of a battery do not change, so the potential of the right plate remains OV throughout, but my question is if the charge on the plate is constantly changing, then how is the potential of the plate not being effected? As negative charge increases on the right plate, is its potential not supposed to decrease?

Comment: If the potential difference between the negative battery terminal and the right plate is not changing (assuming zero wire and switch resistance and an ideal battery) why would you expect the potential at the right plate or at the negative battery terminal to change?

Comment: @BobD , because charge on the right plate is changing?

Answer (score 2):

You are right. After a time interval, potential of the right plate would decrease just as much as it would increase for the left one, assuming you set potential to be 0 at infinity (or anywhere else except on either plates).

Recall that you can freely add any constant to an electric potential without altering any physical quantity. In other words, you are free to choose reference point to measure potential. When you set negative terminal of the battery to be at 0V, it is your referernce point.

For example, let's first set refernce at infinity. After turning the switch on, potential of right plate would be $-\Delta V$ and left plate would be $+\Delta V$. But when you're setting negative terminal of the battery to be your reference point, you'd now say potential of right plate is zero, but the left one is $$V-V_{ref} = \Delta V - (-\Delta V) = 2\Delta V$$
Potential isn't unique, potential difference is, as physical quantities like electric field depends on it.

Comment: yes but I cannot understand why the potential of the right plate remains constant throughout? If at one moment the potential of the right plate is taken as reference point, after some time more charge accumulates on the right plate, so its potential should decrease and become less than the potential we had taken as reference point?

Comment: When you set some point as reference, doesn't matter what happens to that point, it must have 0 potential. If you set reference at infinity, potential at the right plate changes over time, with respect to infinity. If you set the negative terminal as reference, at any time you'll measure potential with respect to potential of negative terminal at that time. At no times does the right plate has any potential difference to the negative terminal. So it's potential remains zero.

Comment: if I set the negative terminal of battery as reference point, the net charge on the negative terminal is maintained constant by the chemical reactions inside the cell, but the charge on the right plate of capacitor connected to the negative terminal is changing constantly, then how are both maintained at the same potential?

Comment: They are connected by a resistance free wire. They have to be at the same potential, since $\Delta V = IR= 0$

Comment: can you explain the mechanism, how this happens?

Comment: Charges don't have much to do with potential. For example, consider a conduting plane near a point charge. The plane has different amount of charges at different points yet the plane has to be equipotential. There is less/no charge in negative terminal and negative charge in the plate doesn't imply that they need to have different potential.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149125/discussion-between-golam-ishtiak-and-aditya-mukherjee).

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are wondering about is explained by a property of a particular component of capacitor design that is called the [dielectric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric)

The dielectric of a capacitor is designed to have a high level of a property called 'electric susceptibility'.

A simplified example of a material with such a property is, say, a fluid with dissolved ions in it. As the capacitor is charged up the electric field of the charged electrodes is exerting an electric force on the dissolved ions, displacing them. With the postively and negatively charged ions displaced relative to each other the dielectric is presenting an electric field that is largely off-setting the electric field between the electrodes of the capacitor. The effect is that as the capacitor is charged up the measured potential between the capacitor electrodes remains pretty much the same.

That property of the dielectric gives the capacitor the capacity to store energy, hence the name 'capacitor'.

In order to have high performance a dielectric needs to have the following two properties that are pretty much opposite requirements.

A dielectic must be a superb insulator, because if the dielectric starts *conducting* electricity, that's a catastrophic failure.

At the same time it is necessary that ions/charge inside the dielectric have leeway to be shifted in position, so that electric field can build, offsetting the electric field from one electrode of the capacitor to the other.

Comment: I am not saying that the potential difference between the plates of capacitor should not change, I am asking that if the charge on the right plate of the capacitor in the picture is changing with time, how does the potential of "that plate" remain constant with time?

Comment: @AdityaMukherjee The thing is: 'potential' is inherently a *relative* designation. What is definable is *difference of potential* between one point and another point. (This goes back to the fact that the value of a potential is obtained through *integration*. For electric field: integration of the Coulomb force with respect to position coordinate. We have that the mathematical operation of integration introduces an arbitrary additive constant.)  Wherever a textbook author writes about 'potential' it is essential to read that as 'difference of potential'.

Comment: when I am saying potential of a plate, I am referring to the potential measured by taking the potential at infinity to be 0, like when I am saying the potential of one terminal of battery is V and other terminal is 0v , I mean they are both measured by taking potential at infinity to be 0.